# Composer error when running specific commands

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to run specific composer commands like update, self-update or diagnose and I keep getting the error below when:

```
  Argument 1 passed to Composer\Config::merge() must be of the type array, null given, called in phar:///usr/local/Cellar/composer/1.0.0-alpha8/libexec/composer.phar/src/Composer/Factory.php on line 92 and defined
```

Other commands like validate, init or about are working. Also running validate doesn't show any errors in my composer.json file.

Things tried to no avail:

- used PHP version shipped with OSX
- used homebrew PHP version
- downloaded and used composer.phar from getcomposer
- used homebrew composer

Has anybody encountered the error and can give advice please?

Cheers,

Stephan

Comment: what specific commands?

Comment: I'm trying to do a `php composer.phar self-update` and `php composer.phar update` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue resolved. Composer uses a `composer.json` file AND the users `config.json` file if one is found in the `$COMPOSER_HOME`. It turned out that I had an empty config.json file in my `$COMPOSER_HOME` causing composer to crash. Removing the file solves the issue.